# No matching function to gloox::ChatStateFilter::ChatStateFilter()

Tags: c++, virtual, gloox

I am receiving the error as per the heading despite using the implementation as defined in the documentation and examples. I'm not sure what is going wrong. There is also the additional error of, `No matching function for call to gloox::MessageEventFilter::MessageEventFilter()` for trying to use that object as well. An example of my code is below:

```
class TuiHangouts : public ConnectionListener, LogHandler, MessageSessionHandler, MessageHandler,
    MessageEventHandler, ChatStateHandler, RosterListener, EventHandler, ChatStateFilter,
    MessageEventFilter
{
public:
    TuiHangouts();
    virtual ~TuiHangouts();
}
```

And within the *.cpp file:

```
GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::TuiHangouts() : m_session(0), m_messageEventFilter(0), m_chatStateFilter(0)
{}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you. The library that I'm trying to implement into my project, as you might have guessed, is the gloox library. Just mentioning it here if it helps.

Please beware that whilst I'm an alright coder, I have no formal education and much of the nomenclature used by such programmers is beyond incomprehensible to me. Just keep that in mind :)

Comment: As far as I can see you are inheriting from `ChatStateFilter`, and it probably has no default constructor you can make use of.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, I have a global `MessageEventFilter *m_messageEventFilter;` and `ChatStateFilter *m_chatStateFilter;` under private. Or isn't that what you're referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [their reference](http://camaya.net/api/gloox/classgloox_1_1ChatStateFilter.html) `ChatStateFilter` doesn't provide a default constructor but only

```
ChatStateFilter (MessageSession *parent);
```

as you are inheriting that class with yours, you need to call the constructor in your member initializer list:

```
GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::TuiHangouts() : ChatStateFilter(&m_session), // ...
{}
```

Comment: Thank you, @πάντα ῥεῖ! But the example source provided something completely different, which is what I provided in my question. As far as I know, I implemented it exactly how it did and got a completely different result. Oh well, another lesson learnt in constructors and inheritance :)